# How to add circular flame restricted within an object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, smoke-simulation, fire

I need a flame inside the following structure:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

The flame needs to be realistic like a bonfire, conical and pointy. Something like this(for shape of flame only not textures and color):

[image: 3]

I tried a sphere for domain and flow:

[image: 4]

But it gave this result:

[image: 5]

The flame needs to be restricted in the bowl like structure.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You have a poor quality reference picture of a cell shaded flame, however your screenshot shows what seems to be an attempt to make a photo-realistic flame. Please clarify what you are after. Please give all the relevant context of your desired results as well - the approach can be very different for a single still image and animation. There can even be different kinds of approaches depending on your camera movement.